# Вопрос по SDK RuStore

Tags: android, kotlin

хочу добавить в своё приложение виджет от RuStore отзывы. Вот здесь документация: **https://help.rustore.ru/rustore/for_developers/developer-documentation/SDK-reviews-ratings**

Вот код который не работает: высвечивается ошибкой reviewInfo

```
manager.launchReviewFlow(activity, reviewInfo).addOnCompleteListener(object: OnCompleteListener<Unit> {
    override fun onFailure(throwable: Throwable) {
        // Review flow has finished, continue your app flow.
    }
 
    override fun onSuccess(result: Unit) {
        // Review flow has finished, continue your app flow.
    }
})
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: А что в ошибке-то написано? Наверняка неверный тип, а какого... типа эта переменная тоже стоит показать (инициализацию)

Comment: Нет она просто подсвечивается красным как ошибка

Comment: Наводим курсор на эту красноту и выскакивает табличка с пояснением проблемы и предложениями  возможных исправлений. И что за привычка пошла читать сообщение только до первого знака препинания?...

Comment: Вот фото моего кода: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/WN3Vit_1TaKL2g

Comment: Вот фото когда нажал: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/OOAEjzkACQfBpQ

Comment: Ну так у вас вообще нет такой переменной. Вам нужно сохранить результат первого запроса и с ним вызывать второй. И на всякий случай напомню что запросы асинхронные - второй запрос должен быть в цепочке вызовов из `onSuccess()` первого, чтобы его результат был доступен во втором.

Comment: А как сохранить. Я просто новичок и не понял каким образом нужно сохранить переменную reviewInfo. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Объявить в классе свойство(поле) и в колбеке присвоить ему полученный объект. Потом это свойство и передать в запрос из вашего вопроса.

Comment: Вы можете пожалуйста написать как это будет выглядеть в коде.

Comment: Без знания основ языка написать сколько-нибудь серьёзное приложение невозможно - берите учебник и учите. Иначе вы тут напостите кучу одинаковых по-сути вопросов по каждой переменной и никто на них отвечать не будет. Мне не жалко написать пример, но он вас ничему не научит, тем более что я могу только на java, на котлине не пишу и знаю его местами немного.